# How to get HTML Table Value created in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy, xml-parsing, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have a situation where I have created the html table for Jenkins Parameter which looks like below and I want to get the value in the Desired Count column for each component if its NOT equal to Current count or if it is null/zero.

For example, if I change Desired Count of A1 to 2, then my Jenkins parameter should return that A1=2 when I build the job so I can update that to proceed further steps in my Jenkins pipeline. Could somebody help

My Table looks like this

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {  
                border: 1px solid black;  
                text-align: center; 
                width: 40%; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>COMPONENT</th>
                        <th>CURRENT SCALE</th> 
                        <th>DESIRED SCALE</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A1</td>
                        <td>-1</td>
                        <td><input type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>B1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>C1</td>
                        <td>-1</td>
                        <td><input type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </html>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the following Groovy code.

```
def text = '''
    <html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {  
                border: 1px solid black;  
                text-align: center; 
                width: 40%; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>COMPONENT</th>
                        <th>CURRENT SCALE</th> 
                        <th>DESIRED SCALE</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A1</td>
                        <td>-1</td>
                        <td><input type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'>1234321</input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>B1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'>555</input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>C1</td>
                        <td>-1</td>
                        <td><input type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </html>
'''

def html = new XmlParser().parseText(text)
println html.table

def values = [:]
html.table.tr.each{ row -> 
  
  if(row['td']) {
    if(row['td'][2].input.text()) {
      values[row['td'][0].text()] = row['td'][2].input.text()
    }  
  }
  
}

println values
```

Output

```
[A1:1234321, B1:555]
```

---

**Update**

Assuming your Active Choice Parameter name is `versions` you can do something like the below to get the parameters. You may have to reply on the order of the inputs.

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                script {
                    def versionParams = params.versions.split(',')
                    A1=versionParams[0]
                    B1=versionParams[1]
                    C1=versionParams[2]
                    println "A1: " + A1
                    println "B1: " + B1
                    println "C1: " + C1
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, your HTML content inputs should be tweeked like below.

```xml
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            table, th, td {  
                border: 1px solid black;  
                text-align: center; 
                width: 40%; 
                border-collapse: collapse;
                }
                </style>
                </head>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <th>COMPONENT</th>
                        <th>CURRENT SCALE</th> 
                        <th>DESIRED SCALE</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>A1</td>
                        <td>-1</td>
                        <td><input class="setting-input" name='value' type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>B1</td>
                        <td>1</td>
                        <td><input class="setting-input" name='value' type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></input></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>C1</td>
                        <td>-1</td>
                        <td><input class="setting-input" name='value'  type='number' step='1' min='0' max='5'/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
             </html>
```

Comment: my question might misinterpret you, but I have already created this table to work in Jenkins UI. Now when I enter values in the DESIRED SCALE column and Build the job, this parameter should return the value that I choose according to the condition that i posted in the question, But I think this solution can only get values from the table on the same parameter

Comment: could you help me with this

Comment: thank you it is working. but also could you help me get the component column values dynamically from the xml?

Comment: @AlfredHitchkock you can use the initial code to extract the other columns. Basically, you may have to define the HTML Template as a global variable in the Pipeline, move the Input Parameter also into the Pipeline, then after Input is given, pass the template and get the corresponding component value. If you need help, feel free to create another SO question.